# tokenizer null character

Tags: java, string, token

```
inputValue = "111,GOOG,20,475.0"

StringTokenizer tempToken = new StringTokenizer(inputValue, ",");

while(tempToken.hasMoreTokens() == true)
{
    test = token.nextToken();
    counterTest++;
}
```

It's giving me some invalid correct NULL character

I started to learn stringtokenizer and I'm not sure at this point what wen't wrong logicly I think it works out but am I forgetting something?

Comment: "It's giving me some invalid correct NULL character" please be more specific:  is this not compiling or is this giving you a runtime error?

Comment: Works fine for me (after fixing syntax errors): http://ideone.com/AGyj2

Comment: @daiscog giving me errors as I run it

Comment: And what precisely is the error it is giving you?  (Can you copy and paste the error message?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some typo in your code. 
However,using [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) is discouraged in new code. From the javadocs:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.

The recommended way is to use [String#split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).
Something like:

```
private void customSplit(String source) {
    String[] tokens = source.split(";");
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens; i++) {
        System.out.println("Token" + i + "is: " + token[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet is working with some minor adjustments, *maybe your missing something simple*, so check the rewritten full example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String inputValue = "111,GOOG,20,475.0";

    StringTokenizer tempToken = new StringTokenizer(inputValue, ",");

    int counterTest = 0;
    while (tempToken.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String test = tempToken.nextToken();
        System.out.println(test);

        counterTest++;
    }

    System.out.println("-------------------");
    System.out.println("counterTest = " + counterTest);
}
```

Output:

```
111
GOOG
20
475.0
-------------------
counterTest = 4
```